# bootstrap / jquery popovers on jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble getting bootstrap's popovers to work properly on jsfiddle.

Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/fX7hn/17/

I have included hosted bootstrap.css and boostrap.js from the bootstrap CDN, but I still get errors that suggest something isn't being loaded right:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'popover'`

Anything obvious?

UPDATE: fixed bad path to js lib an error is gone, but popovers still aren't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason it doesn't include it properly..

This is in the HTML:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/"//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Include it manually by adding the following to the HTML

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

---

You bind the click event before you put any elements that will accept it on the page. Move

```
$("a.info").popover().click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

to the bottom.

Comment: @sachleen-- you're right! Thanks- fixing the path did correct the error. However, the popover still isn't working.

Comment: see my update. At the time you bind the click event, there are no links it can bind to.